# Trying to build a list of results from webpage using beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, beautifulsoup

StackOverflow,

I am a college student looking for help. I am working with a group to build a mysql database that will eventually represent all North American video games in an ER diagram. I am trying to grab all the titles from the list in the link:https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/category/999-all?region=1

There are 745 pages and I am trying to grab all of the video game titles and put them into a single xml doc or something I can easily manage in order to import later into a database.

If someone could kindly guide me in the right direction I would be very grateful!!! I have all the required modules and applications installed on ubuntu to run beautifulsoup but if there is a better method to obtain the information I will try that way as well.

I am running the latest version of ubuntu and I am using python3 with pip3 installed as well.

The code I currently have is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from websockets import headers


URL = 'https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/category/999-all?region=1'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'results'})
gameNames = results.find_all('td', class_="rtitle")

for name in gameNames:
title = name.text
print(title)
```

Thank you,

Martin Scurlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the titles to text file, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/category/999-all'

params = {
    'page': 0,
    'region': 1
}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for page in range(0, 746):
        print('Page {}...'.format(page))
        params['page'] = page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        for title in soup.select('td.rtitle'):
            print(title.text, file=f_out)
```

This saves all titles to `data.txt`:

```
_dive
_OUR_:_Defense
_space_train
-Color ball-
-Earth - Wind - Fire-
-KLAUS-
-lily of the hollow-
-sora-
-SPROUT-

...and so on.
```

Comment: Awesome!! That is so helpful, thank you! 

Will the speed in which I grab the information be important? I know that some sites might ban ip's if you try to grab too much too fast? 

Again, this looks amazing!

Comment: I did end up getting kicked out of the request. I am about to try the following.

I imported time, and added a sleep period of (2)

Comment: Just to keep this thread up to date on what I did incase someone else comes along looking for help. I ended up adding my "purpose and email" to the (User-Agent) section. Since this was for educational purposes I put that it was educational and listed my student email address. 

I imported time at the top of the script and I put "time.sleep(1)" at the end. Everything is running. Just slowly. It has been running for about an hour and a half and has completed 94/746 pages.

Not sure if there would be a way to speed it up without my ip being blocked again.